# Why do I get a 500 internal server error when trying to access an html file in public_html using cPanel/godaddy?

Tags: html, .htaccess, dns, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have a godaddy website hosted through cPanel, but the html file, named test.html, will not appear when searching "website_name"/test.html. This is the contents of the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>TEST</body></html>
```

There is no .htaccess, although permissions are set to 644. The server displays the 500 error regardless of whether a valid address was entered. Additionally, the DNS domain and the actual ip address show different things: The DNS shows an index page I can't find in my public_html, whereas the ip shows the godaddy "Future home of something quite cool." message.

Background: I inherited this project as part of a new job. I can set up an apache server with php and mySQL support (in fact I went from using an xampp install to just running everything from command line for practice), but my employer has two godaddy domains: one made using a website building, and one using cPanel for which I am to write my own HTML, CSS, php, js, etc. I have searched extensively across godaddy, google and stack exchange, and have found nothing so far that has worked. The cPanel File Manager has a couple files in it, but nothing will open as a url (I can edit the files though). I checked the godaddy documentation and follow the tutorials and nothing has helped. Any help is appreciated. As an aside, I’m wondering if it would just be easier to completely restart the whole process? The html/css/php files are kind of a hodgepodge and would require rewrites anyway, and bootstrap is used as a source file in every one but never actually implemented. The environment is very relaxed so long as I’m working on something productive.

Comment: edit: Upon navigating to preview website, I inserted some test into the website so the "Future home of something quite cool." now has "test" appended to it. Still not showing up on either though.

Comment: Check if hidden files are visible in cPanel's file manager. That might be the reason for not seeing the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I enabled show dotfiles and a search for .htaccess showed nothing. I created my own htaccess in my home (not root) folder, and set permissions to 777 I believe. I’m not sure off the top of my head but I set it so everyone can edit, view, and execute <i>briefly</i> before changing it back because I still did not have the desired output i.e. any at all.